# TYPO3 8.7 : MM_match_fields not kept when editing a record

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I’d like to create a relation between pages and other tables (for example news and fe_users).
For that, I create 3 fields in the tables concerned (news or fe_users).
Each field is a MM selection for pages that are attached to a given category using this config

```
'policies' => [
    'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:=:0',
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => $ll . 'tx_relations.policies',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
        'foreign_table' => 'pages',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND pages.uid IN (SELECT uid_foreign FROM sys_category_record_mm WHERE sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 1 AND sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = "pages") ORDER BY pages.title ASC, pages.uid ASC',
        'MM' => 'tx_pages_references_mm',
        'MM_match_fields' => [
            'tablenames' => $tablename,
            'fieldname' => 'policies',
        ],
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 9999
    ]
],
'working_groups' => [
    'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:=:0',
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => $ll . 'tx_relations.working_groups',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
        'foreign_table' => 'pages',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND pages.uid IN (SELECT uid_foreign FROM sys_category_record_mm WHERE sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 2 AND sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = "pages") ORDER BY pages.title ASC, pages.uid ASC',
        'MM' => 'tx_pages_references_mm',
        'MM_match_fields' => [
            'tablenames' => $tablename,
            'fieldname' => 'working_groups',
        ],
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 9999
    ]
],
'networks' => [
    'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:=:0',
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => $ll . 'tx_relations.networks',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
        'foreign_table' => 'pages',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND pages.uid IN (SELECT uid_foreign FROM sys_category_record_mm WHERE sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = 3 AND sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = "pages") ORDER BY pages.title ASC, pages.uid ASC',
        'MM' => 'tx_pages_references_mm',
        'MM_match_fields' => [
            'tablenames' => $tablename,
            'fieldname' => 'networks',
        ],
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 9999
    ]
],
```

When saving the record,

I have the following records in the DB

```
 uid_local uid_foreign    tablenames                   fieldname      sorting
 1         129            tx_news_domain_model_news    policies       1
 1         130            tx_news_domain_model_news    working_groups 1
 1         131            tx_news_domain_model_news    networks       1
```

Which seems correct to me...

But when I edit the record in the BE, every page is unselected...

So, INSERT seems ok, but SELECT seems down... Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?